# How to not get TIMEOUT (Infinite loop) error

Tags: java, infinite-loop

The user inputs integers and the program determines the even max and even sum.

The program output is correct but I get an error at the end that says "TIMEOUT (Infinite loop?)". Is there a way that I'm supposed to end the loop?

```java
static void evenSumMax() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("how many integers? ");

    int size = sc.nextInt();
    int integer[] = new int[size];
    int sum = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        System.out.print("next integer? ");
        integer[i] = sc.nextInt();
        if (integer[i] > 0 && integer[i] % 2 == 0) {
            sum += integer[i];
            if (integer[i] > max) {
                max = integer[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("even sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println("even max = " + max);
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89nQi.png)

```
❌ You passed 0 of 3 tests. Try again.

test #1: 4 (2, 9, 18, 4)

expected output:
how many integers? 4
next integer? 2
next integer? 9
next integer? 18
next integer? 4
even sum = 24
even max = 18

your output:
*** TIMEOUT (infinite loop?)
how many integers? 4
next integer? 2
next integer? 9
next integer? 18
next integer? 4
even sum = 24
even max = 18

differences:
0a1
> *** TIMEOUT (infinite loop?)

result:
❌ fail

details:
exceeded maximum allowed run time
```

I tried different compilers online and they are not giving me this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your code as (well-formatted) text, not as a picture. By the way, by itself, that code shouldn't result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Is only the method `evenSumMax()` tested, or your whole program? Maybe some other part of your program (e.g. the caller of `evenSumMax()`) causes the issue? How is the test implemented; i.e. in what case does it log "*** TIMEOUT (infinite loop?)"?

Comment: The timeout error is not coming from Java. You either have placed this method into an existing program or are running it on an obscure website that we can't help you with. Contact your teacher for help.

Comment: There is no infinite loop in your code.

Comment: Do you need to handle non-numeric input? What happens if the test enters "boom" for the first question ("how many integers?")?

Comment: Note that the "TIMEOUT" is printed before your actual program output. Where is `evenSumMax` called? What is the `static void main(String[] args)` method in your program?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code prints "TIMEOUT (infinite loop?)". Nevertheless, there is room for optimization.

You are only ever using the last value from your array, immediately after setting its value. This means that for large inputs, your program first needs to allocate one *huge* array. Depending on the runtime environment, this can crash or take a long time.

Get rid of the array and simply store the "next integer" in a single `int` variable. Use that single variable to calculate the sum and the max. You should not need more than 4 variables: `size`, `nextInteger`, `sum`, `max`.

If that doesn't work, talk to your instructor.